# IIS Log Parser-Python

Tags: parsing, iis, python-2.7

[Apachelog parser](http://code.google.com/p/apachelog/) is a nice Project which can be used to parse a apache log file. Are there any other python modules to parse an IIS log file other than [this](http://code.google.com/p/spilp/) one?

Comment: Did you ever find any alternatives to spilp?

Comment: @Abundnce10 What I did was converted the IIS in to apache log format and used the "Apache Log Parser" ..:)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a regex pattern to parse IIS log files and feed them into fluent, and then elasticsearch.

Here is the pattern:

```
/^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+)(?<s_ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+)(?<cs_method>.+?\s+)(?<cs_uri_stem>.+?\s+)(?<cs_uri_query>.+?\s+)(?<s_port>\d{1,3}\s+)(?<user>.+?\s+)(?<c_ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+)(?<csUser_agent>.+?\s+)(?<sc_status>\d{1,3}\s+)(?<sc_substatus>\d{1,3}\s+)(?<sc_win32_status>\d+\s+)(?<sc_bytes>\d+\s+)(?<cs_bytes>\d+\s+)(?<time_taken>\d+)?$/
```

This leaves out User Agent info though.

Hope it gets you going.